# PBKDF2 is a Non- FIPS Complaint Algorithm?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, password-encryption, fips

PBKDF2 algorithm is used in `SimpleMembership` provider (Universal Provider) 2.0. Is it a Non-FIPS Complaint Algorithm? Please ensure the correct solutions?

Comment: Websecurity.createuserandaccount has FIPS Non-Complaint Algorithms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> PBKDF2 algorithm is used in simplemembership provider(universalprovider) 2.0 is a Non- FIPS Complaint Algorithm.

If I am reading this correctly, there are three questions here. First, you are asking about an implementation detail of `SimpleMembership`. Second, you are asking if `PBKDF2` is approved for use in FIPS validated cryptography. Third, you are asking if `SimpleMembership`'s PBKDF is approved for use.

**First**

I seem to recall `SimpleMembership` uses a non-standard PBKDF. You should be using `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` in `System.Security.Cryptography`.

Generally speaking, the FIPS approved algorithms and validated implementations are located in `System.Security.Cryptography` and they are **non-managed**. In fact, according to KB 811833, ["System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing" security setting effects in Windows XP and in later versions of Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811833):

> Microsoft .NET Framework applications such as Microsoft ASP.NET only
>   allow for using algorithm implementations that are certified by NIST
>   to be FIPS 140 compliant. Specifically, the only cryptographic
>   algorithm classes that can be instantiated are those that implement
>   FIPS-compliant algorithms. The names of these classes end in
>   "CryptoServiceProvider" or "Cng." Any attempt to create an instance of
>   other cryptographic algorithm classes, such as classes with names
>   ending in "Managed," cause an InvalidOperationException exception to
>   occur.

**Second**

`PBKDF2` is approved for use if its using an approved hash. Since `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` uses HMAC/SHA-1, you will not be able to use it. NIST SP800-56 and SP800-57 are pretty clear about the choice of hashes for collision resistance.

However, your use case is a little different - SHA-1 is being used as a Pseudo Random Function (PRF). But I'm only aware of one exception where SHA-1 is allowed to be used as a PRF, and that's in TLS. The exception is a footnote in SP800-108 (IIRC).

**Third**

`SimpleMembership`'s PBKDF is not approved for use.